# Is there any closed-form expression to calculate each element of the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Considering a generic square matrix $A=(a_{i,j})$ we want to compute its inverse $A^{-1}=\left[a^{(-1)}_{i,j}\right]$.

Is there a way to express each $a^{(-1)}_{i,j}$ using a closed form expression?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Analytic_solution

Comment: Depends on what you mean by closed form. Cramer's rule involves det.

Comment: Yeah by closed-form expression I mean a set of rules that involves elementary operations... For example, cofactors are calculated using minors, If I wanted to replace the cofactor term in the relation with an expression, how would it be... What I'd like to reach is a final formula not involving more steps to calculate the final quantity. Maybe it is not possible, just want a confirmation of this if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $ij$ entry of $A^{-1}$ is $(-1)^{i+j}$ times the determinant of the matrix $C_{ji}$ obtained by deleting row $j$ and column $i$ from $A$, all divided by the determinant of $A$. I don't know whether you consider that to be a closed form.

Comment: Since the formula is a rational function in the entries of $A$, it should be good :)